# Masonry scrolling over my fixed nav bar

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-masonry

A nav bar underneath my header sticks to the top of the screen after scrolling past the header.

This worked fine, with posts disappearing 'behind' the nav bar, until I added Masonry.

Now, the posts go over the top of the nav bar as you scroll.

See for yourself [here](http://news.enigma-tech.co.uk).

It sticks by:

```
$(function() {
    var nav_offset_top = $('#nav').offset().top;
    var nav = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_top > nav_offset_top) { 
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
        $('#jump a').css({ 'color': '#D7D7D7' });
        } else {
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
            $('#jump a').css({ 'color': '#303435' });
        }
    };
    nav();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        nav();
    });
});
```

and then the header/nav/Masonry:

```
<body>
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
        </div>
        <div id="wrap" class="js-masonry">
            <div id="container">
```

Appreciate any help, I've tried putting in extra div elements, but I don't really know what else to do.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Fixed it.

For some reason I thought z-index was either horrendously complex, or not allowed/frowned upon in CSS3.

I added `z-index: 1;` to `#wrap` and `z-index: 2;` to `#nav`.

Job's a good'un.